# valgrind report strange memory usage

Tags: c, valgrind, realloc

I have a large array and I expand it with realloc() and use valgrind to see memory usage.

here is minimal example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PASSES      1024 * 2

#define MEMTOALLOC  1024 * 1024

int main(void) {
  void *remem = NULL;
  void *newmem;

  const unsigned int chunk = MEMTOALLOC / PASSES;

  unsigned int i;
  for(i = 0; i < PASSES; i++){
    const unsigned int size = (i + 1) * chunk;
    newmem = realloc(remem, size);
    if (newmem == NULL){
      printf("No memory!\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    remem = newmem;

    if (i % 1000 == 0)
      printf("%10u processed\n", i);
  }

  free(remem);
}
```

If PASSES is 1, program realloc everything at once and valgrind reports:

```
total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,048,576 bytes allocated
```

If PASSES is 100, program realloc gradually with 100 reallocs and valgrind reports:

```
total heap usage: 100 allocs, 100 frees, 52,949,250 bytes allocated
```

and if I do PASSES 1024, I get huge consumption:

```
total heap usage: 1,024 allocs, 1,024 frees, 537,395,200 bytes allocated
```

What is the explanation of this memory usage?

Comment: You don't have any code. You don't have any questions. What do you expect to see in response to your post?

Comment: Code not really needed, but I will edit my question.

Comment: This is a case where you can probably solve your own problem simply by attempting to create an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: If memory buffer is being relocated (i.e. pointer returned by realloc isn't the same it got as parameter), then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @keltar - what exactly makes sence? sure pointer is not the same, this is why i assign it to the v->buffer. Old pointer is not valid anymore, i do not need to free it.

Comment: I am editing the question and posting MCVE now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where `PASSES` is 100, you have `chunk = 10485`. 
The allocations you are doing are

```
 i+1      size
  1      10485
  2      20970
  3      31455
 ...      ...
 100   1048500
```

You can add up all of those sizes, or if you know that the sum of 1 to 100 is

```
100 * 101 / 2 = 5050
```

then you can easily calculate the total memory allocated as

```
5050 * 10485 = 52,949,250
```

which is exactly what valgrind is reported.  That's not to say that you have 52MB allocated at any particular time. Only the that the total memory requested from `realloc` over the lifetime of the program was 52MB.

If `PASSES` is 1024, then `chunk = 1024`, and the calculation is

```
(1024 * 1025 / 2) * 1024 = 537,395,200
```

Again, you never have more than 1MB allocated at any particular time, but the total amount of memory requested from `realloc` was 537MB.

Comment: I see. Just one question then - how one can see total memory consumption at the peak?

Comment: @Nick Try `valgrind --tool=massif`. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and result was lower than i expected, and i got confused.